# Does Go automatically close file description in some cases?

Tags: go

I am trying to detect the file descriptions opened by Go but don't closed on purpose. In other words, I am trying to make my code "wrong", with resource leaking.

My code is

```golang
func hh(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f0, err := os.OpenFile("notes.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    // I don't close file
    fmt.Println(io.ReadAll(f0))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/req", hh)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

I use shell script file `` FCOUNT=`lsof -p $1 | grep -v " txt " | wc -l`;echo "PID: $1 $FCOUNT" | sort -nk3 `` to print out how many file descriptions belong this Go program.

No matter how many requests I send to this server (`curl http://localhost:8080/req`) the number is still 10 on my MacBook. For sure, I check with `Activity Monitor` and get the same answer.

PS: my first version of code actually was using `http.Get` and didn't close the response `Body`. Have same situation too.

My env: `macOS Big Sur 11.2.3`, `go version go1.16.2 darwin/amd64`

Does anyone know why the file description number keeps still when I thought it should leak? Is my shell script wrong? Or Golang does some tricks inside?

Thank you!

**Update**

The problem is I am checking the process named `go` instead of my folder name. Go truly gives me an additional `go` program, look like a daemon, and it cannot show fd details. The real program shows fd leaking clearly. Still, I got some knowledge from answers and comments about golang's GC.

I am gonna close this question.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Fd -- *"If f is garbage collected, a finalizer may close the file descriptor, making it invalid; see runtime.SetFinalizer for more information on when a finalizer might be run. On Unix systems this will cause the SetDeadline methods to stop working. Because file descriptors can be reused, the returned file descriptor may only be closed through the Close method of f, or by its finalizer during garbage collection. Otherwise, during garbage collection the finalizer may close an unrelated file descriptor with the same (reused) number."*

Comment: The os package sets a finalizer that may close the file at some point. The program leaks fds on my system.  I am also running `macOS Big Sur 11.2.3, go version go1.16.2`

Comment: @mkopriva does that mean I have to turn off GC when I running my program to see fd number increasing? Like `env GOGC=off go run .`

Comment: @CeriseLimón which method you used to detect the fd leaking? Same command as my?

Comment: `lsof -p 19343 | grep notes.txt |wc`  with second script executing `curl http://localhost:8080/req` in a loop.  The number of open fds approaches 950 before the finalizers kick in.

Comment: @ccQpein Is it possible that you are measuring the wrong process? Check to see that you are using the id of the process executed by `go run` and not `go run` itself.

Comment: @CeriseLimón you are right, go run actually gives an additional `go` process, like a daemon, and it cannot show fd details. When I find the real go program, it truly leaks several fd when I sent requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Burak Serdar notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66713418/1256452), it's possible for open files to be closed during gc.  That means the answer to the question as asked in the subject line—"Does Go automatically close file description in some cases?"—is "yes".  But the *in some cases* here is doing a lot of heavy lifting.

The point at which garbage collection actually occurs is generally difficult to predict (though you can invoke the GC code yourself deliberately).  The point at which a finalizer runs is even more difficult to predict, since some work may be done in separate goroutines.  See [How to stop the golang gc and trigger it manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38972003/1256452) for more information and note that each release of Go may change some rules about the internals of GC (though the action of `GOGC` is pretty stable).

Answer (score 1):

In Unix, open files are closed by the garbage collector:

https://golang.org/src/os/file_unix.go line 186